# Roblox Hat Retexturing

Tags: mesh, texturing, image, uv-image-editor

So I wanted to retexture Roblox hat [Scoobis](https://www.roblox.com/catalog/4155516700/Scoobis). I got the original mesh obj. which looks like this:[image: Scoobis mesh]

And original texture of it which looks like this:

[image: Scoobis texture]

And i dont know how to attach this texture into mesh in Blender to make it look like original (first link) so i can modify it in Blender. When i try to do it, the result is something like this:
[image: scoobis3]

Do i need to "unwrap" mesh properly to match texture or what?

Edit:
[image]

Comment: The answer is yes, you need UVs.  Where did you get the mesh from, and also how did you apply the texture?

Comment: As Dale says you need to unwrap your mesh to get a UV, and also plug an Image Texture node (with your image loaded) into a Diffuse. But the UV you'll have will probably not fit with the image, maybe share your file so that we can test? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I got mesh from mesh library from creator of this hat. (creator profile ->scroll down -> meshes). I added textury by simply unwraping mesh (default: U -> unwrap) and thats how it looks like: 

https://imgur.com/a/qXmR9ly 

You may wonder why I won't create my own texture from scratch. The problem is that first I want to match the original texture to the mesh, because hat textures in roblox works in a way, when at example, if original texture got eye in top left corner, then top left corner of image is always assigned to be placed in place of eyes on the mesh. I uploaded blend file in post